# Partitioning the natural numbers to finite number of arithmetic progressions

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

Some already asked on this site whether the natural numbers can be partitioned to finite number of arithmetic progresions with distinct differences, with the condition that the intercection between them is the empty set. My question is, removing that assumption - if you let the intercection to not be empty, is it still false?

Comment: Please include a link to the earlier question in your question. It doesn't change the answer to your question, but someone might like to refer to the other question to see what changes if we require the intersection to be empty.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25313/finitely-many-arithmetic-progressions there you go

Comment: Thanks! I was searching only math.stackexchange; I did not think of looking in mathoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After taking $a_n=2n+1$, $b_n=4n+2$ we are left only with multiples of $4$.
Each of the progressions $c_n=3n$, $d_n=6n+4$, $e_n=12n+8$ covers one third of these.